# Web Mail client setup for postfix server

Tags: postfix, mail-server

I have an Ubuntu server with postfix installed.

How can I set up a simple webmail package, so I can send email from a web interface to and from the local accounts and gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is **squirrel mail**:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squirrelmail

Certainly not the best web mail client ever, but easy to set up and reliable. A more fance client is **roundcube**. The `roundcube` package is included in the multiverse repository.

Both solutions need an IMAP mail delivery agent. So you might need the `dovecot-postfix` package or something similar.

Comment: i've installed roundcube yesterday.. it looks good.. but i coulnt receive mail from other domains... should i open separate port for these incoming mails..

Comment: receiving mails is not a question of roundcube but of postfix. For receiving Mails you need a MX record entry in your DNS-entry. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mx_record to find out what the XM record is. Without the MX record the sending mail server will not know where to route the mail to.

Comment: i've set my MX record same as A. is that wrong..?

Answer (score 1):

a very perfect installation guide is [here](https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix2.9.6-dovecot2.0.19-mysql) .

and if evrything worked fine use this for [webmail](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squirrelmail)

Have good time with these long configurations

Comment: As much as I agree to the post and voted I think it still needs more explanations that just "a very perfect installation guide is here .".

Answer (score 0):

For my opinion the best one is Roundcube http://roundcube.net/ or you can also try RainLoop http://rainloop.net/

Last one has ability to try it as demo.

Answer (score 0):

it's useless to have your own hosted mail server. google always finds a way, to delay or to blacklist every mail from your server. google is bad, but with some small money, you can be his friend. subscribe the cheapest google workspace (about 9usd, cmiiw), and use its smtp relay. google smtp relay, have unlimited mail quota, and doesn't sacrifice your mail server / internet speed. i was forced to make friend with google, because i have internet load-balance failover, with dynamic public ip (google assume that ips as mail spammer).

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, G-mail is the best web mail client ever. You can have G-mail interface on your server if you sign up to Google Apps. If you run business, it cost some money, but it pays in the end. Check it out, I have very good experience with apps. You also get other google web applications such as docs, calendar etc.

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/

If you run small company (up to 10 users), non-profit or for education, you can use apps for free:

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html

Comment: Google apps is entirely run on google's infrastructure..!! i need something to run in my own server